# How can I have code inside a function that executes other functions in typescript / javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using the following coding pattern:

```
function submit() {

    function submitModalDone() {
        // do something
    }

    function submitModalFail() {
        // do something
    }

    $.ajax(
       {
           url: "xxx"
       })
       .done(submitModalDone)
       .fail(submitModalFail);
}
```

I placed the submitModalDone and submitModalFail inside the submit function as these are only called from the $.ajax.

However is it a good idea to just add my code as is to the end of the function and after all of the child functions. Is there a design pattern that would be a better fit for this? It seems strange that the $.ajax code and other code just sits there outside any container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a decent, descriptive pattern.

You might want to structure it like this, however:

```
var submit = (function () {

    function submitModalDone() {
        // do something
    }

    function submitModalFail() {
        // do something
    }

    return function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "xxx"
        }).done(submitModalDone).fail(submitModalFail);
    };

}());
```

This avoids creating `submitModalDone` and `submitModalFail` every time `submit` is called.

Comment: This is very interesting. Is it true that using this pattern if the submit works then submitModal fail will not get created? If I need to pass in an argument such as link then how could I do that using your pattern?

Comment: From a js-perspective, no, that's not true. The function submitModalFail will be created but not executed. Whatever modal etc you create within that function though will not be created, since the function is not executed.